# Use GREP on array to find words

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, debugging, command-line

Given the following array in Shell Programming

> foo=(spi spid spider spiderman bar lospia)

I would like to use GREP to search for all words in the array which has the 3 letters `spi`

> Correct output : spi spi spider spiderman lospia

I have tried something like this

```
foo=(spi spid spider spiderman)

grep "spi" foo
```

But it seems it is wrong , what is the correct way to go about it ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will print out all words that contain spi:

```
foo=(spi spid spider spiderman bar)
for i in ${foo[*]}
do
    echo $i | grep "spi"
done
```

Answer (score 22):

The simplest solution would be to pipe the array elements into grep:

```
printf -- '%s\n' "${foo[@]}" | grep spi
```

A couple of notes:

**printf** is a bash builtin, and you can look it up with `man printf`. The `--` option tells printf that whatever follows is not a command line option. That guards you from having strings in the `foo` array being interpreted as such.

The notation of `"${foo[@]}"` expands all the elements of the array as standalone arguments. Overall the words in the array are put into a multi-line string and are piped into grep, which matches every individual line against *spi*.

Comment: It may worth to translate it back into an array 
`bar=$(printf -- '%s\n' "${foo[@]}" | grep spi | tr '\n' ' ');`

Comment: Definitely the most helpful answer here. Substantially more efficient than

```bash
for entry in "${foo[@]}"; do
    if echo "$entry" | grep spi &>/dev/null; then
        results+=("$entry")
    fi
done
```

which is what I had originally. Doing this instead improved performance by orders of magnitude:

```bash
results+=($(printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}" | grep spi))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IFS=$'\n' ; echo "${foo[*]}" | grep spi
```

This produces the output:

```
spi
spid
spider
spiderman
lospia
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to run the script/extract under the exit-on-error shell flag ('-e') and unnecessarily exiting the script/extract whilst also avoiding the tedium of wrapping the code in "set +e" … "set -e", I always use case since unlike grep(1) or test(1), it (case) doesn't update $? …

```
for f in "${foo[@]}" ; do 
    case "$f" in
        *spi*) echo $f ;;
    esac
done
```